# VB.net создание своего визуального компонента

Tags: visual-basic

Как создать свой компонент (понимаю что вопрос обширный, но может на толкнете на обширную инструкцию )))
В общем.. есть к примеру компонент DataGridView.. понятное дело его изменять нельзя, да и не требуется.
Я лишь хочу чтоб у меня был такой же компонент, но чтобы тип поля поля (оно же колонка) можно было выставить ProgressBar.

Т.е. к примерку создаю там таблицу из двух полей:
1) "Name" - просто имя 
2) "Progress" - прогресс отображаемый в виде ProgressBar, задаваемый мною.

И в результате увижу подобное (только проценты в виде прогресс бара, который выставляется как тип поля):

- Редиска 60%
- Морковка 20%

Как это можно осуществить :)

PS: создавать DataTable с типом поля ProgressBar пробовал - ошибку выдает что DataGridView не знает такого типа и не может его показать. Ну да ладно, а как создать такой компонент свой пофиг на этот грид.

Comment: Куда проще выводить картинку.

Comment: Не не не.... Всякие подобные ухищрения как предложили уже "вывод картинок" и т.п. обходные пути не интересуют. Поиск и использование чужих/других компонентов тоже.
Вопрос - "Как создать свой компонент ?...".

Comment: Ну, как обычно - выбрать проект компонента и создавать. Там все просто, но долго и скучно.

Comment: Согласен, если это не Express версия (в ней нет такого, урезанка). Да и даже еслиб было - не умею ))) Дайте инструкшинл подробный(ссылку)!
Ну и желательно для совсем ручной работы инструкцию (если это поддерживается в vb.net без спец.раздела проект компонента)

Comment: Решение найдено ! Напишу как разберусь в нем. 
А то, что ответ на свой вопрос нельзя давать - бред.

Comment: @IvanZakirov Отвечать на свой вопрос можно.

Comment: в общем решение большое. Ответ дать не могу пока нет 50 очков, комментарий решение не вмещает. Сами ищите в общем ответ на этот вопрос )))))))